# jquery force http:// on value with no http://

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to force urls entered into the search box to have "http://" forced on to them because the url doesn't work without it.

```
var mySite = $('.search').val();

if (mySite -="http://"){
   alert('http://').append(mySite);
};
```

Sorry if this code is horribly wrong I'm just trying to hash out the idea here.

Comment: It seems pretty horrible. Why are you doing this client-side instead of on the server?

Comment: I'm trying to get this to happen in an offline environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want case-insensitivity

```
$('.search').val(function(_,oldValue){
  return /^http:/i.test(oldValue) ? oldValue : ('http://'+oldValue);
});
```

…Or you can just

```
$('.search').val(function(_,oldValue){
  return oldValue.indexOf('http:') ? ('http://'+oldValue) : oldValue;
});
```

Comment: This worked for me.. if ( mySite.indexOf("http:") != 0 ) mySite = "http://"+mySite;

Answer (score 5):

First get the jQuery object representing the search box. Then check to see if it's value starts with `http://`. If it doesn't, then change the value so that it does.

```
var search = $('.search');

if(search.val().indexOf('http://') != 0) {
    search.val('http://'+search.val());
}
```